# Is there a way to include files several directories up without using "../"

Tags: php

I have a server set up with several directories on it. 
I have this file that needs to include a php file 3 directories up.

`include "../../../folder/neededThis.php"` works just fine but if your doing it several times on different functions it becomes a chore to count how many directories back a file is.

Is there a way to include a file by specifying the entire path instead of using "`../`"

Eg. `include function(path/to/my/folder/neededThis.php);`

Comment: You can use the absolute path, but it's not recommended.

Comment: Yes, it's specified in [the documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php). In your case it'll probably involve messing with the `include_path` setting.

Comment: Why is that not recommended? Are the precautions the moving of files or is it some other conflicts? @blues

Comment: If you ever deploy the project to a different machine the absolute path is very likely different.

Comment: You can just use `getcwd()` in your index file and write it to a constant. Then you wont have problems deploying else where.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]` as this would always return the root folder of whatever you're working on. An example implementation of this:

```
<?php
 $file = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."path/to/my/folder/needThis.php";
 echo "#LOC: ".$file; //output where is the file
 include $file; 
 #rest of code....
?>
```

It would return something like this:

```
#LOC: server/path/to/my/folder/needThis.php
```

---

However if your file gets moved to a subdomain of the server you need to tweak the affected files, a way to circumvent this is to use `getcwd()`

For example: if your file gets moved to a subdomain (example: `server/subb`) the above script will return something like so:

```
#LOC: server/path/to/my/folder/needThis.php
Warning: include(server/path/to/my/folder/needThis.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in server/subb/index.php on line 4
```

If we replace `$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]` with `getcwd()` the problem won't happen.

Take precaution, I have no idea what would be the security risks of using this method.